# Can the value of the NFTs be added to the stake size of the pool?

Tags: ada, nft, staking, contracts, metadata

Many small stake pools struggle with increasing their stake. The stake could be increased by adding the value of all the NFTS held in wallets by both delegators and operators. How do we determine value? Once we have smart contracts, value will be the last sold price of the NFT, recorded in the Blockchain.

Answer (score 3):

If the value of NFTs (their purchase price or last traded value) were to be added to staking then both the ADA used to purchase them and the NFT would counted.  This would make it possible to double your staking rewards by selling an NFT to yourself or a collaborator.

It would also affect the [Cardano monetary policy](https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/explore-cardano/cardano-monetary-policy.html).

Stake pool operation is a serious undertaking and gathering enough stake to establish a viable pool is part of that challenge.

Comment: There is also the appreciation of value of existing NFTs based on new traded prices... basically impossible to know what "total staked value" would be at any given time when counting NFTs. Many opportunities for adversarial behavior. "Affect the monetary policy" is an understatement, it would need a complete rewrite!

Comment: I completely agree with the remarks. Just an idea: is there a possibility the NFT to be 'locked' somehow (under another smart contract) within the stake pool and it's last sold value (written in the smart contract) to be added to the stake? By 'locked' I mean not to be traded in any way, or if traded its recorded value to be deducted from the stake.

Answer (score 1):

Only ADA coins are participating in staking and securing the network. NFTs will not be part of stake for stake pools.